# Why am I getting this KeyError using multiprocessing and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing on a fuzzy matching script I've written, I need to go through 1.4 Billion comparisons and it takes 30+ hours without multiprocessing so I'm attempting to integrate it here.

```
def fuzzyCompare(data1, data2):
    print("Performing Fuzzy Matches...\n")
    similarityDf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Similarity Ratio", "Id1", Id2])
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(data1)):
        str1 = data1["CompanyName"][i] + "," + data1["Address1"][i] + "," + data1["City"][i] + "," + data1["PostalZip"][i]
        str1 = str1.lower().replace(" ","")
        for j in range(len(data2)):
            str2 = data2["Company"][j] + "," + data2["Physical Street 1"][j] + "," + data2["Physical City"][j] + "," + data2["Physical Postal Code/ZIP"][j]
            str2 = str2.lower().replace(" ","")
            ratio = fuzz.ratio(str1,str2)
            if(ratio > 0):
                similarityDf.at[count, "Similarity Ratio"] = str(ratio) + "%"
                similarityDf.at[count, "Id1"] = data1["Id1][i]
                similarityDf.at[count, "Id2"] = data2["Id2][j]
                count = count + 1
    print("Performed " + str(len(data1)*len(data2)) + " Fuzzy Comparisons.\n")
    return similarityDf

def main():
    data1 = readData(excelFile1) *#read excelfile into dataframe*

    data2 = readData(excelFile2) *#read excelfile into dataframe*

    df_split = np.array_split(data2, 4) *#split data2 into 4*

    args = [(data1, df_split[0]),
            (data1, df_split[1]),
            (data1, df_split[2]),
            (data1, df_split[3])]

    with mp.Pool(processes=4) as p:
         outputData = pd.concat(p.starmap(fuzzyCompare, args))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.freeze_support()
    main()
```

I have a print statement at the end of my `fuzzyCompare()` and it prints the result for only 1 worker then I receive the following error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "C:\Users\...\Documents\Code\Python\fuzzyCompare\multiFuzzyCLI.py", line 47, in fuzzyCompare
    str2 = data2["Company"][j] + "," + data2["Physical Street 1"][j] + "," + data2["Physical City"][j] + "," + data2["Physical Postal Code/ZIP"][j]
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1068, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4730, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiFuzzyCLI.py", line 145, in <module>
    main()
  File "multiFuzzyCLI.py", line 132, in main
    outputData = pd.concat(p.starmap(fuzzyCompare, args))
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 276, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
KeyError: 0
```

I know what a KeyError is, I just don't understand how it's getting the error in this case. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a `KeyError` because you try to index every DataFrame with an index starting from 0, and `np.array_split` will maintain the original Index of each split.

To properly index the `i`-th row of a DataFrame you should **always** use `DataFrame.iloc` as this works in general for any Index, not necessarily a RangeIndex that begins from 0. So you need to change all of your selections to be of the form:

```
data2["Company"].iloc[j]  # Not data2["Company"][j]
```

---

#### Worked Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'CompanyName': list('abcdefghij')})
df_split = np.array_split(data2, 4)

# For first split this works as we get lucky the index starts from 0
data2 = df_split[0]
for j in range(len(data2)):
    print(data2['CompanyName'][j])
# a
# b
# c

# Later slices fail; `df_split[1].index` is RangeIndex(start=3, stop=6, step=1)
data2 = df_split[1]
for j in range(len(data2)):
    print(data2['CompanyName'][j])
# KeyError: 0

# Instead properly select with `.iloc`
for j in range(len(data2)):
    print(data2['CompanyName'].iloc[j])
# d
# e
# f
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this fixed everything and it works perfectly now :)